# Is returning auto_ptr from functions wrong/error-prone?

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

Let's say I'm using `std::auto_ptr` in my code.*

Is there any danger in returning an `std::auto_ptr` object?
i.e. Could it result in a memory leak, undefined behavior, etc.? or is it a safe use of `std::auto_ptr`?

<sup>*I'm **not** asking if there is a better substitute (like `shared_ptr`); I'm specifically asking about the pitfalls of returning `auto_ptr` itself.</sup>

Comment: It's not wrong and it's not error-prone. `auto_ptr` works perfectly for that case.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Cool, thanks, just wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything (a direct answer didn't come up in searches).

Comment: Although you're right about this functionality of auto_ptr, bear in mind that it is deprecated in C++11 and `unique_ptr` is preferred instead.

Comment: @the_mandrill: Yup I'm aware, it's still useful though. Namely when trying to stay backwards-compatible, as well as when the result might be used in `boost::ptr_vector::push_back` or whatever.

Comment: This is exactly what `auto_ptr` was designed for.  The original proposal was for something more like `scoped_ptr`, and some one (I think it was Bill Gibbons) pointed out that they'd found the transfer of ownership semantics very useful for things like factory methods.  The result was `auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it's safe and can lead to more robust code. It should not lead to a memory leak since the memory pointed to is automatic deleted.

But there are some cases where you have to take care:

- **Copies** of `auto_ptr` are **not equal**!
- Construction of one `auto_ptr` from another will **release** the object the first pointer was pointing to

Please see here:

1. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm
2. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/auto_ptr.html

> The auto_ptr template class is designed to help manage memory in a semi-automatic way and prevent memory leaks when unexpected events such as exceptions would otherwise have caused the normal cleanup code to be skipped.

*(quoted from (2))*